# First row ignored by Data Grid View in C# Linq

Tags: c#, database, forms, linq

I have a program which basically creates, reads, edits, and delete from a linq database. 
It does function well on different rows, however when I select the first row to delete it, it acts as if there is no ROW selected so it returns me a "Select Row" output warning.

In addition when I click modify on the first row, it always edits the row below it only. (The other rows are not affected)

This is the 'event update' code in the class :-

```
 public int UpdateEvent(int selectedRow, string name, DateTime date, string eventType, string eventVenue)
    {
        EventTicketEntities database = new EventTicketEntities();
        Event selected = database.Events.Where(x => x.EventId == selectedRow).FirstOrDefault(); //selected row will give the id of the row
        if (selected == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            selected.EventName = name;
            selected.EventDate = date;
            selected.EventType = eventType;
            selected.EventVenue = eventVenue;
            return database.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

This is the code of the 'event delete' in the class:-

```
 public int DeleteEvent(int selectedRow)
    {
        EventTicketEntities database = new EventTicketEntities();
        Event eventDelete = database.Events.Where(x => x.EventId == selectedRow).FirstOrDefault();
        database.Events.Remove(eventDelete); //We use this method to delete the particular customer 
        return database.SaveChanges(); //returns the affected rows ....

    }
```

This is the code of the button of the form:-

```
  private void btnModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedRow != -1) //if not selected do nothing
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Modify", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                EventBL eBL = new EventBL();
                int result = eBL.UpdateEvent(SelectedRow, eventName.Text, calendar.Value, cmbEventType.SelectedValue.ToString(), cmbEventVenue.SelectedValue.ToString());
                 MessageBox.Show(result + " rows affected!" + SelectedRow);
                 dgvEvents.DataSource = eBL.GetEvents();
                 dgvEvents.Refresh();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            EventBL eBL = new EventBL();
            MessageBox.Show("Select Row first" + SelectedRow);
            dgvEvents.DataSource = eBL.GetEvents();
            dgvEvents.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

This is the code of the delete button:-

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedRow != -1) //if not selected do nothing
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                EventBL eBL = new EventBL();
                int result = eBL.DeleteEvent(SelectedRow);
                MessageBox.Show(result + " rows affected!");
                dgvEvents.DataSource = eBL.GetEvents();
                SelectedRow = -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select Row first");
        }
    }
```

And this is the code of the event handler of data grid view:-

```
 private void dgvEvents_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > 0)
        {
            SelectedRow = int.Parse(dgvEvents[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Take care-
HurpaDerpa

Comment: the _first_ row has `e.RowIndex == 0`... so change `if (e.RowIndex > 0)` to `if (e.RowIndex > -1)`

Answer (score 0):

by the way، selected will always get a value it can't be null 
So the condition 
If (selected==null)
Will always be false
Because you assign .firstordefault